# Django + InnoDB: random failure of model reading

Tags: python, mysql, django, innodb

I have a project in django which has been working well on the development server but doesn't on the hosting server.

Since I don't have access to the console on my hosting server, I created the tables by copying output from `python manage.py sql <app name>` to the SQL query section in phpMyAdmin on the hosting server.

In my app I have two models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    creationDate = models.DateField('date created', auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    publicationDate  = models.DateTimeField('date published', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
            get_latest_by = "publicationDate"

    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id)

class Text(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, db_index=True)
    answerId = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=5, default = "uk", choices=settings.LANGUAGES)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    imgPath = models.CharField('path to the image representing the question/answer', max_length=255, blank=True)
    colourId = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.text
```

I also have the Admin page generated by Django:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from survey.models import Question, Text

class TextInline(admin.StackedInline):
    fields = (('answerId','language','text','colourId'),)
    model = Text
    extra = 3

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (('author','publicationDate'),)
    inlines = [TextInline]

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
admin.site.register(Text)
```

Now on the development server everything works fine. I can add questions, texts in different languages for each question, save it, and then open it and see what was stored.

On the hosting server The part of creating question and texts works. When I check the SQL table, all information is stored there. But when I want to look at the saved question in the Admin view, it always shows the information of the Question object, but Text objects associated to it are sometimes showed, but most of the time none is showed.

Also on the page which should show available models in the Admin view, the Text object is also often missing, and showing sometimes after few reloads of the page.

To me it looks like some problem with connection to the database.

The hosting is using MySQL 5.5.29, tables were created with default engine InnoDB.
Configuration in Django is the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '?????????',
        'USER': '?????????',
        'PASSWORD': '??????????',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
}
```

}

I tried to vary the `CONN_MAX_AGE` and `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` parameters but it didn't help.

What can cause such a behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not sound like a database connection issue, this sounds like one of the following:

- Caching
- You modified your python files and have not restarted the web server process (e.g Apache)  to update the python files.

I suggest you try reloading your python files on the hosting web server using one of the following methods:

```
$ touch wsgi.py
```

or

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

I am assuming your web server is Apache otherwise use the appropriate command to restart your web server.

Comment: This partially solver the issue. The `Text` object started to show in the Admin page always, but then another issue was due to non ASCII characters retrieved by the form which I solved by the `@python_2_unicode_compatible` in front of each Model definition.

Thanks for help.